# How would you say "root locus" (in robotics) in Latin?

Tags: new-latin, modern-life, mathematics

"Root locus" is a diagram showing where the poles of a closed-loop system are depending on the amplification (gain) in the open-loop system. How would you say that in Latin? My attempt would be literally translating the Croatian phrase "dijagram mjesta korijena", "diagramma locorum radicum".

EDIT: The "root" here means "the value for which the polynomial is equal to zero". For example, the roots of the polynomial x^2-x-1 are 1.618 (the Golden Ratio) and -0.618. Here is what a root locus looks like, I think it will become clear what it means:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about robotics to understand that explanation. Can you explain what sense of the word "root" is involved?

Comment: Is this the same sense of "locus" that is used in geometry (close to "set"), as in e.g. "conjugate locus"? I imagine that to be attested in Gauss or Riemann or at least Euler or Newton.

Comment: @Draconis "Root" as in "the value for which a polynomial is equal to zero".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes, it is a curve.

Comment: Since you're talking about polynomials, I added the `mathematics` and `new-latin` tags. I'm afraid I still don't quite get it, but maybe someone else will.

Comment: I think I recall root being _radix_ in the algebraic sense/s